# Files needed to run a standalone exe built with wxWidgets

Tags: wxwidgets

I have built an EXE with wxWidgets 3.1.4 under Visual Studio 2017.

I can start the EXE from Visual Studio but not outside Visual Studio.

I get the message:

Unhandled unknown exception; terminating the application.

EXE is built in Release/x86.

I have tried to copy the Release DLLs of wxWidgets in the same folder as the EXE as well as files from vc_redist_x86 but I still get the error.

Thanks for your help

Comment: @MaximeVerner, can you run the Debug version of the application and see where the crash occurs?

Comment: A resource file was missing, it is present with .cpp files but not in the Release folder. I would not have seen it in Debug since the file is present but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was an application error, a resource file was missing.

I have deleted the Release folder, rebuilt and copied the resource file and the EXE runs.

Release DLLs are in my %PATH% and I have installed vc_redist_x86.exe so I guess these two things allow my standalone EXE to start.

Comment: ypou shuold consider making a static build of your application. Unless you are making an additional DLLs...

Comment: Not sure how, I am using prebuilt binaries of wxWidgets. A static build involves rebuilding wxWidgets, right?

Comment: @MaximeVermier, just build it yourself. What compiler do you use? It is very easy to build...

Comment: I use Visual C++. What is weird is that even after having removed all Visual C++ redistributables, the executable still starts.

Answer (score 0):

@MaximeVermier,

In order to build the library yourself:

1. Open ${WXWIN}\build\msw\wx_vcN.sln.
2. Select Build->Batch Build...
3. Select all project which says "Debug/Win32"
4. Click "Build".

The resulting libraries will be in ${WXWIN}\lib directory.

Now all you need is to change the project file for your application and rebuild.

Then you will not need wxWidgets DLLs.

Comment: Thank you Igor, I should try this.

Comment: @MaximeVernier, let us know if you will have any issues with that. You could also try to statically link the CRT, but it will require changing all the projects (wxwidgets and yours). So, I'd advise you not to do that. Besides the CRT might change in the future.

Comment: Successfully built Debug/Win32. I have modified the project this way: VC++ Directories: prepended %WXWIN%\lib\vc_lib and Linker\Input\Additional Dependencies: added wxbase31ud.lib and wxmsw31ud_core.lib but the exe is still bound to DLLs.

Comment: @MaximeVernier, check the `minimal` sample default project solution. Your own solution should have 2 settings, especially if you copied it from `minimal`. Select the appropriate configuration and rebuild.

Comment: I have built minimal and seen it does not depend on DLLs. I have tried to copy the minimal folder elsewhere, adjust the location of core and base in the .sln but the project minimal does not load for some reason.